# Mix_Halt specific tracks?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

In SDL Mix is there a way to halt a specific Mix_Music track? Eg. something like this:

```
//music1 = the target music track to halt
if(condition)
{
    Mix_Halt(Music1);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `Mix_Music` track.
When you start to play music with [`Mix_PlayMusic`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC57),
the previously playing music will automatically be halted (possibly with a fadeout).
If you want to explicitly halt the currently playing `Mix_Music` track,
you can use [`Mix_HaltMusic`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC67).

If you want to control sounds concurrently, you should use [`Mix_Chunk`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC16) objects instead.
These are samples that can be played on multiple [channels](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC25),
which can be controlled individually, e.g.:

```
Mix_Chunk* chunk1 = Mix_LoadWAV("chunk1.wav");
Mix_Chunk* chunk2 = Mix_LoadWAV("chunk2.wav");

Mix_PlayChannel(1, chunk1, -1); // Play chunk1 on channel 1
Mix_PlayChannel(2, chunk2, -1); // Play chunk2 on channel 2

if (condition)
    // Only halt channel 1, while channel 2 keeps playing
    Mix_HaltChannel(1);
```

You can find all this information in the [documentation](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`Mix_Pause`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_32.html#SEC32) or [`Mix_HaltChannel`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_34.html#SEC34) function which pauses specific channels if that's what you're after.